# GitLog Command with Path

Tags: git, git-log

I try to make a GitLog from projects in diffrent places.
Is there any solution to add a Path at the GitLog command ?

I try this but it doesnt work :

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H \"%an\" %ad \"%s\"" --numstat --date=short -- Code/code1/git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add --git-dir before log command

`git --git-dir=Code/code1/.git log --pretty=format:"%H \"%an\" %ad \"%s\"" --numstat --date=short`